# Type Mismatch error in Excel but not in Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I get a `type mismatch` error when I try to run this in Excel...

```
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheets

Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
Set wks = wkb.Worksheets(1)
```

When I do the same thing in Access (including a `Dim app as Application.Excel`) I have no issues.

What am I over looking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type is incorrect. You have defined "worksheets" and then trying to assign a single "worksheet"

change the :

```
Dim wks As Worksheets
```

to:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
```

should work.

Comment: Apperantly today is not my day. So simple. So much time lost. Arrrgh!

Comment: Will check your answer as the right one as soon as the system lets me.